# Converting String Data Values with two commas from csv or txt files into float in python

Tags: python, string, csv, txt

I just received a dataset from a HPLC run and the problem I ran into is that the txt data from the software generates two dotted separated values for instance "31.456.234 min". Since I want to plot the data with matplotlib and numpy I can only see the data where the values are not listed with two commas. This is due to every value which is smaller than 1 is represented with one comma like "0.765298" the rest of the values is, as aforementioned, listed with two commas.
I tried to solve this issue with a .split() and .find() method, however, this is rather inconvenient and I was wondering whether there would be a more elegant way to solve this issue, since I need in the end again x and y values for plotting.

Many thanks for any helping answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very clear regarding comma and dots.
For the decimal number you say that you have comma but you show a dot : 0.765298

I guess you can not have dots for either thousand separator and decimal...

If you have english notation I guess the numbers are:
"31,456,234 min" and "0.765298"

In this case you can use the replace method :

```
output = "31,456,234"
number = float(output.replace(',',''))
# result : 31456234.0
```

---

**EDIT**

Not very sure to have understood what you are looking for and the format of the numbers...

However if the second comma in 31.456.234 is unwanted here is a solution :

```
def conv(n):
    i = n.find('.')
    return float(n[:i]+'.'+n[i:].replace('.',''))

x = '31.456.234'
y = '0.765298'

print(conv(x)) # 31.456234
print(conv(y)) # 0.765298
```

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the misunderstanding but I mean dot (in German we say comma) sorry for that. So yes basically all values are separated with dots and like I noted with the "31.456.234 min" the value would be 31.46 min, however, the system puts out a way to accurate value and with two dots instead of only one. And the same thing happens with the Absorbance value.

Comment: Do you mean 31.456.234 = 31.456234 ?

Comment: Yes exactly is just rounded.